# Can't set image as background (SKScene)

Tags: sprite-kit

I have tried various different ways to do this and nothing works.  Here's my code.  If I change to a UIColor instead of using patternImage it works fine.  I just want a static image as the background.  I appreciate any advice I can get!  Thanks!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView

    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    scene.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "IMG_6999")!)
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting background color, not an image.
In `didMove(to view:)` of GameScene.swift you need to create SpriteNode that will be contain your image. Then add this node to the scene.
For example:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
  let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
  background.zPosition = -1  //other nodes will be higher then background node
  background.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
  addChild(background)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me.  I copied exactly (replacing "background" with "myfilename" for imageNamed).  Still see black background.

Comment: Ok...used a different image and it worked!  I'll investigate what's wrong with my image (I suspect it's size related).  THANKS!